# Why does western law treat criminal and civil violations so differently

Tags: political-philosophy, knowledge, society

**Example 1, criminal act:** You find a set of keys on the ground and use them to obtain access to a nearby xyz, taking it away for your own use.  You make no effort to pay for the xyz.

**Example 2, violating a civil contract**: You pass someone on the street who is selling their xyz. You promise to pay them $N within T time frame and sign a paper to the effect.  The seller hands you the keys and you use them to obtain access to the xyz, taking it away for your own use. You make no effort to pay for the xyz.

Generally, to the best of my knowledge, Example 1 will result in far more serious legal repercussions from the state then Example 2.  Doesn't Example 2, when written this way seem like a **bigger** problem to society then Example 1?  Shouldn't that then warrant an ***equal or greater response*** from the state?

This is a philosophical question where all parties have perfect knowledge of what they are doing, and the laws of the state have no way of verifying that knowledge either way.  Also, an answer which can cover multiple cases for XYZ will be preferred (i.e. car theft, insurance fraud, theft of intellectual property, and counterfeiting vs. passing bad checks)

Comment: I'm not sure how much this is a philosophical question so much as a query on why "Western" law is what it is; which is a far more cultural, political, and historical question. Maybe I'm wrong - I can see a possible answer in the philosopher models after which "Western" law was designed.

Comment: I think you're making an error in how you're understanding example 2. Example 2 as worded sounds like it could be a clear case of fraud -- which would be a criminal act. Civil law exists precisely for cases where violation of contract is not clearly criminal.

Comment: There ain't no such thing thing as Western law. Do you mean English common law (which the American legal system is derived from) or Roman law which the French and Spanish systems follow? Different animals.

Comment: This question is not a legal question regarding specific existing laws.  This is specifically a philosophical question on why modern laws are written such that two (nearly) identical actions result in two very different degrees of punishment.  Also note that the state has no knowledge of intent in the 2nd example, it only knows a contract has been broken.  I would expect arguments like: the state rewards "crafty" criminals or the state punishes "chaotic" criminals or a history of "crafty" criminals has paid off lawyers to their benefit and "chaotic" criminals have had no such benefit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is intent. Modern law in most countries (which is what I presume you mean by western law) determines punishment both by the consequences of an act and by the intent of an act. Take for example the differentiation of the act of killing a person into premeditated murder and manslaughter. In the examples you gave, in the first case his intention was clear and is thus judged as a criminal act. In the second case, it would be very difficult to prove that he didn't intend to pay, it is just as likely that he might have wanted to pay but was unable to for some reason or another. If they somehow could prove that he never intended to pay from the very beginning, then he could be charged with fraud, which is a criminal offense not a civil one.

Comment: ok, I can see how knowing the intention of a criminal may help to judge them.  The threshold may be too high or too low, but that's a separate issue